How can I save NIfTI images separated into directories based on protocol name?
In GitHub page dcm2nii DICOM to NIfTI converter (README):

… you may want to invoke additional options, for example the call dcm2niix -z y -f %p_%t_%s -o /path/output /path/to/dicom/folder
will save data as gzip compressed, with the filename based on the protocol name (%p) acquisition time (%t) and DICOM series number (%s), with all files saved to the folder "output".      …

Is there a command that allows you to save images into separate folders
based on the protocol name?
